# Bash, exec and the quoting hell

Tags: bash, escaping, quotes

How can I preserve single and double quotes when running a command using exec?

```
#!/bin/sh

CMD="erl -eval 'erlang:display("foo")'"
exec $CMD
```

Tried with backslashes, but didn't help. For example, if I do what it would sound ovious to me:

```
#!/bin/sh

CMD="erl -eval 'erlang:display(\"foo\")'"
echo $CMD
exec $CMD
```

I get as output of the `echo` exactly what I want, but the command is not executed correctly when using `exec`.

I'm working on Snow Leopard.

Any help?

Comment: Don't Do That.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an array:

```
CMD=(erl -eval 'erlang:display("foo")')
echo "${CMD[@]}"
"${CMD[@]}"
```

Comment: Just what I was typing too. You seem to have missed the single quotes in the argument though - it looks like the OP wanted single quotes around that last argument: `\''erlang:display("foo")'\'`

Comment: Hmm, doubt it, but let the OP speak.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you use `eval` instead of `exec`, if this is the last thing in your script it won't make a huge difference operationally...

```
#!/bin/sh

CMD="erl -eval 'erlang:display(\"foo\")'"
echo $CMD
eval $CMD
```